# CSS inside PHP statement

Tags: php, css

I have a php statement inside my body so that my one page does not take property of body

```
<body id="page-top" class="single" <?php $actionId = $this->context->action->id; $pages =Yii::$app->params['page']; if(!in_array($actionId,$pages) ? 'style="padding-top:10px;"' :'')  ?>>
```

Everything is working but not CSS. Have I inserted it in wrong place?

```
'style="padding-top:10px;"' :'')
```

Comment: You're using ternary incorrectly.  You don't need an `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just forgot the echo before `'style="padding-top:10px;"'`?

Also you use the `if` AND `?`-Operator. Just use one of them :)

```
<body id="page-top" class="single" 
    <?php 
        $actionId = $this->context->action->id;
        $pages =Yii::$app->params['page'];
        echo (!in_array($actionId,$pages)) ? 'style="padding-top:10px;"' : '';
    ?>
>
```

Comment: This has no errors but CSS is still not working on the page!

Comment: Sorry, i forgot a closing `)`

Answer (score 8):

You're not `echo`ing the style. Furthermore, you're mixing ternary operator and normal if syntax.

```
<body id="page-top" class="single" <?php $actionId = $this->context->action->id; $pages =Yii::$app->params['page']; echo (!in_array($actionId,$pages)) ? 'style="padding-top:10px;"' :''  ?>>
```

You can use either the ternary operator:

```
echo ($condition) ? "true" : "false";
```

Or the normal syntax:

```
if ($condition) echo "true";
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment!  I copied this code, it has no errors , but the page is still same . The css is not working

Comment: It must be something with the operands in the condition, did you check them? See [here](https://3v4l.org/H9Gp2), I set $pages to `[2, 3]` and `$actionId` as 1, and it shows the style correctly.

Comment: It worked! the only problem was i had to use echo (in_array($actionId,$pages))  instead of echo (!in_array($actionId,$pages))

Comment: I see, you had the condition the other way around :) glad you got it working!